# Why do I get nullable reference errors when generating a model using Entity Framework Core in a .NET Core 3.1 console app?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a C# based .NET Core 3.1 console application. I've installed Entity Framework Core and generated a DB model.

Now I'm getting the following error:

> Feature 'nullable reference types' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater

When I go to the `Project -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced...`, I see:

> Why Can't I select a different C# Version?

How do I either correct this error? How do I upgrade my language version of C#?

Is there a way to manually force it to C# 8 by updating the project file manually?

Comment: These classes were generated by EntityFrameWorkCore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project targets .Net Core 3.1 it should support using C# 8.

You can tell compiler specifically which language version to use adding

```
<LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
```

statement next to the `<TargetFramework>` in your csproj file. Then the compiler will tell you, if there are any problem.

Make sure your have .Net Core 3.1 SDK installed.